# Django: Set many-to-many value to a model

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing

I am trying to test my Models `Project`, `Category` and `Tag`. I'm running into an issue when trying to add tags to my project model.

It won't allow me to do it in the `Project` model itself for eg.

```
self.project = Project.objects.create(
...
tags=Tag.objects.create("HTML5"),
)
```

Django docs suggest the I do it as below. However I can't "add" the `Tag` without saving the model and I can't save the model without adding the `Tag`

## Tests

```
class ProjectTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        self.tag = Tag.objects.create(name="HTML5")

        self.project = Project(
            title="Oaks on Main Shopping Center",
            url="www.oaksonmain.co.za",
            image=SimpleUploadedFile(
                name="test-image.jpg",
                content=open(
                    "static\\images\\test_images\\florian-olivo-4hbJ-eymZ1o-unsplash (1).jpg", "rb"
                ).read(),
                content_type="image/jpeg",
            ),
            description="Beautiful website created for Oaks on Main Shopping Center in Knysna!",
            category=Category.objects.create(name="Website"),
        )

        self.project.save() <- Problem here
        self.project.tags.add(self.tag)  <- Problem here
        

    def test_project_model(self):
        self.assertEqual(f"{self.project.title}", "Oaks on Main Shopping Center")
        self.assertEqual(f"{self.project.url}", "www.oaksonmain.co.za")
        self.assertEqual(
            f"{self.project.description}",
            "Beautiful website created for Oaks on Main Shopping Center in Knysna!",
        )
        self.assertEqual(self.tags.count(), 3)
        self.assertEqual(self.category.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(self.image.count(), 1)

    def test_project_listview(self):
        resp = self.client.get(reverse("index"))
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(resp, self.project.title)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(resp, "page/index.html")
```

## Models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]  # Always show latest projects first
        verbose_name_plural = "Projects"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"{title}/")
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="categories")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", verbose_name="tags")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("index")


class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("index")


class Tag(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("index")
```

Comment: Exactly what problem arises if you try to save the object *without* tags. There is for the given model nothing that stops one from saving the `Project` without `Tag`s.

Comment: It gives me this error ```OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<personal filepath>\\media\\<django.db.models.fields.CharField>'```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the `tags`, but with the use of `SimpleUploadedFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first save the tag or the model object, and then later you link the tag as (one of) `tags` of that `Project`, so:

```
html5_tag, __ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name='HTML5')
self.project = Project.objects.create(
    # no tags=…
)
self.project.tags.add(html5_tag)
```

Your `ImageField` also should work with a *callable* for the `upload_to=…` parameter, so:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # …
    def upload_image(self, filename):
        return f'{self.title}/{filename}'
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image)
    # …
```